# Format Text File using Angularjs from Nodejs

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, html, twitter-bootstrap

i ma using `nodejs` with `express` to read the content of a text file using node in the backend.

when i hit the service i get the data on the front end.

```
Object {data: "s1:- hi thank you for calling my name is oh…↵s1:- no worries your welcome bye mam
↵s2:- bye
↵", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

I am able to get the text but i need to format these text based on some keywords such as s1 and s2 and add line break, bold to it on the fly and display that data using `angular`

Comment: i have added <pre></pre> but i need further formatting as my string contains line break and i am preserving it

Comment: can you create a fiddle so that we can figure out what is your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion is if you have access to the file and you control the content maybe you can use Markdown and then use a directive like: [angular-markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive)

if you can't change the contents you would have to create your own directive that will effectively find and replace those tags in the content and convert them into HTML. and then you can use `ng-bind-html` to render the output.

it will look something like:

```
angular.module('specialParse', [])
    .directive('specialParse', function() {
        return {
            template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                scope.content = attr.specialParse
                    .replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />') // Replace line breaks
                    .replace('s1', 'something') // Special tag
                    .replace('s2', 'somethingElse'); // Special tag
                    // ..... And so on.
            }
        }
    });
```

And the HTML

```
<div special-parse="data"></div>
```